# tfs work items (e.g. risk) - need to copy current *html* field values to another new html field

Tags: tfs

I was planning on doing it in excel and publishing the changes back to TFS but I'm getting TF84013, which [this link](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/559803/unable-to-edit-steps-to-repro-and-expected-result-in-test-cases-exported-to-excel) says is because html editing in excel is "In short, edit from excel in any HTML field is not supported at this time."

Any ideas? Do I have to go directly into TFS, I'm trying really hard from SQLing the DB directly, I think I'd sooner write a little console app to do it for me.

Comment: ---Since posting I've come to the solution I need to write a console app with a WIQL update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to interact with the SQL Database to solve your problem. (and you should always stay away from that).

There's an API for TFS that is really easy to use where you can open a Work Item, then update its fields and save it. So the best way is to write a little tool to do that.

Look at [this post](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/28885-How-access-TFS-work-items-using-TFS-API.aspx) as a starting point.

Answer (score 1):

And this API can be used from PowerShell as well if you have both Team Explorer and Powershell on the same system. A piece of sample code updating a work item can be found here:

https://serverfault.com/questions/311222/how-to-modify-a-tfs-item-by-using-powershell

Comment: I wondered if it could be done with powershell, thanks for the link, I'll have a play with it when I'm back at work.